# JavaScript: стоит ли избегать стиля написания кода "функция в функции"?

Tags: javascript, code-style

Допустим, у нас есть JavaScript приложение с большим количеством виджетов. Рассмотрим на примере шапки. Функция `initHeader()` собирает все нужные для дальнейшей работы DOM-объекты внутри шапки, добавляет обработчики событий, вообщем готовит к её использованию. Соответствует ли приведённый ниже шаблон кода "правилам хорошего тона" написания кода?

```
function initHeader(){

    // объекты виджета, с которыми будем работать в функциях
    var var1 = $('#div1');
    var var2 = $('#div2');
    // ...


    // вспомогательные функции

    function function1(){
        // ...
    }

    function function2(){
        // ...
    }

    function function3(){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Особенность этого шаблона в том, что все вспомогательные функции находятся внутри основной.

Зачем такая структура? Согласно книге Роберта Мартина "Чистый код", в идеале у функции не должно быть аргументов вообще, а если аргументы неизбежны, то должен быть один, максимум два аргумента. Но в нашем случае, внутри вспомогательных функций может быть нужно большое количество переменных: jQuery-объекты, какие-то константы, рабочие переменные наподобие времени анимации, какие-то введённые данные и так далее. Если написать все вспомогательные функции вне основной, то тогда придётся всё это передавать в виде аргументов, и в два аргумента уложиться едва ли получится. Такая структура, которую я показал, избавляет нас от необходимости передавать аргументы, при этом все переменные, будучи объявленными внутри `initHeader()`, за пределами данной функции недоступны.

Второй плюс данного подхода в том, что он позволяет единыжды собрать все DOM-объекты через функцию `jQeury()`, а потом уже обращаться к ним через имена переменных (если это корректно называть кэшированием DOM-элементов, то можно сказать, что данный шаблон кода создаёт условия для обеспечения кэширования DOM-элементов).

И ещё: это следует из названия функции, но всё же уточню, что сама функция `initHeader()` вызывается только один раз (это можно сделать в HTML-коде сразу после закрывающего `</header>`, например), а внутренние функции уже могут быть вызваны сколько угодно раз.

Приведите, пожалуйста, аргументы за и/или против такого подхода.

Comment: Боюсь, что я что-то не так понял (слишком уж очевидная у меня мысль), но если у вас имеются какие-то данные, на генерацию которых компьютер ранее затратил ресурсы, то эти данные нужно передавать в виде аргументов, а не генерировать каждый раз внутри функции лишь потому, что Роберту Мартину так нравится. Ну и я не понимаю, к чему это ограничение аргументов по количеству, ведь вы можете передать их внутри одного объекта хоть миллион.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Это следует из названия функции, но всё же я должен был сказать, что сама функция `initHeader()` выполняется только один раз, например её можно вызвать после HTML-кода шапки, тогда функция выполнится после вывода шапки в браузер. Все вспомогательные функции могут быть вызваны в любой момент (пример вспомогательной функции - обработчик кнопки поиска в шапке).

Comment: по моему тут правильный подход. замыкания в JS для того и сделаны, что бы можно было содержать набор нужных нам переменных и функций не загромождая глобальную область видимости

Comment: Реальность такова, что будь Вы христианином Вас примут за своего христиани. Будь Вы сатанист Вас примут как своего сатанисты. И на самом деле все по своему правы и сказать что Вы должны делать так или так, тоже означает навязывать Вам какую-то религию, хоть и другую. Я не понимаю для чего нужны замыкания в таком виде. Если для не загрязнения глобальной области, то для этого придумали модули. А в остальном они нужны только тем, кто пишет на в функциональном стиле. Хотя в данной реализации это просто обычные процедуры и следовательно стиль не функциональный, а процедурный.

Comment: Объясню, зачем нужны. Первое и самое главное: чтобы избежать ресурсозатраной процедуры захвата DOM-элементов внутри вспомогательных функций. Мы один раз захватываем их (например функцией `jQeury`) и теперь мы можем работать с ними из вспомогательных функций, если они объявлены внутри основной. Представьте, что нам нужна одна и та же кнопка в `initHeader` и во вспомогательной функции. Тогда, если вспомогательная функция объявлена вне основной, придётся либо передавать кнопку в виде аргумента, либо захватывать её заново, что нехорошо для быстродействия.

Comment: кстати, тут надо разделить о чём говориться выше - о performance или о качестве паттерна, применительно, в частности к Javascript...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Javascript этот стиль используется для ограничения области видимости вложенных таким образом функций, с целью предоставлять только необходимые внешние интерфейсы (с аналогичной целью, как приватные методы в C++). См. например, [паттерн модуль](http://largescalejs.ru/module-pattern/), [фасад](http://largescalejs.ru/the-facade-pattern/). Таким образом, ничего плохого тут не сделано, только в исходном примере паттерн недоразвит.

Замечу, что нет необходимости добавлять собранные скрипты в `header`, лучше это сделать в конце `body`, чтобы на момент их загрузки все элементы разметки уже были обработаны.

А условие загрузки определённой части кода (модуля) должно быть независимо от факта старта скрипта, управляться специальной сущностью - например инициализацией виджета или роутингом.

Что касается упомянутой в вопросе *рекомендации использовать один или менее аргументов у функции* - надо понимать, что в контексте Javascript это просто забавно звучит и, вероятно, должно пониматься как-то иначе. Всё-таки, это мультипарадигменный, в т.ч. [функциональный, язык программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Т.е. да, конечно, вместо множества аргументов лучше использовать [каррированные функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и их [композиции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9). Далее, с озвученной в вопросе целью, передаётся один аргумент - объект, что, вместе с сахаром [ES6-деструктуризации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) и той или иной системой проверки типов, даёт самые гибкие средства для передачи групп сущностей в/из функции.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Интересно. А что Вы подразумеваете под "инициализацией виджета"? Та функция, которую я привёл в пример, и инициализирует виджет (а именно хедер, но не важно). Однако Вы явно имеете ввиду под "инициализацией виджета" что-то другое.

Comment: строго говоря, это может быть что угодно

Comment: таймер или document.registerElement или render компонента - т.е. имеется ввиду сущность, инициализрующая ваш модуль

Comment: дополнил ответ про количество аргументов

Comment: Более забавно звучит что ЛУЧШЕ использовать каррирование.

Comment: чем же оно хуже?

Comment: впрочем, вы правы, оно не лучше и не хуже, равно и тех же цепочек (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

Comment: Я не знаю какие аргументы у OmerDale против каррирования, один из аргументов обычно - это сравнительно медленно на большинстве движков.

Answer (score 1):

> Согласно книге Роберта Мартина "Чистый код", в идеале у функции не должно быть аргументов вообще, а если аргументы неизбежны, то должен быть один, максимум два аргумента.

Разве он при этом не предполагает, что это должны быть чистые функции?

> Такая структура, которую я показал, избавляет нас от необходимости передавать аргументы, при этом все переменные, будучи объявленными внутри `initHeader()`, за пределами данной функции недоступны.

А вот это мне кажется вообще прямо противоположным рекомендации про функции.

Я считаю, что в большинстве случаев именованные функции должны получать то, с чем работают, через параметры.

Comment: А если того с чем они работают, штук пять или десять? Это совершенно не означает, что функция большая; это может быть узко-специализированная функция.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, параметры всегда можно объединить в объект, и передавать в функцию _один_ параметр

Answer (score 1):

Вложенные функции создают замыкание, а замыкание действительно позволяет сделать "что-то" недоступным, но нужно ли так вообще делать? Очень часто люди употребляют в одном предложении такие слова как `замыкание-инкапсуляция`, `инкапсуляция-приватность`, `приватность-защита каких-то данных от злоумышленников`. Нет, это неправильно! 
Инкапсуляция предлагает скрывать работу с более низкоуровневым api и очень часто предлагает это реализовывать при помощи синтаксического сахара модификаторов доступа, к каковым относится и `private`. Модификаторы доступа в свою очередь созданы чтобы защититься от самого страшного врага кода - разработчика, но не для сокрытия данных, которые подменит или украдет злоумышленник. Это просто выдумки, ведь злоумышленником не нужно изменять Ваш код чтобы что-то украсть.

Настоящая цель замыкания, это защита глобального пространства от засорения всем чем только его можно засорить.

Но ведь Вы задали конкретный вопрос и наверняка хотите услышать на него ответ.

Вложенные функции, это причина нечитаемости кода. Вложенные функции, это причина утечек. Вложенные функции при каждом вызове своего контекста создаются заново. Вложенные функции при этом бывают очень удобными в малых дозах.

Возможно, кто-то ещё добавит аргументов и это Вам поможет определится с выбором.

Когда-нибудь Вы как обычно сядете писать код и Вас озарит чувство, что сегодня Вы впервые написали так, как когда-то читали об этом в умной книжке. И именно такие моменты срывают пелену непонимания и открывают новые просторы для размышлений и осознания того, как нужно писать. За одну долю секунды Вы понимаете очень большую часть информации, которая до этого Вам казалась просто набором несвязанных слов. Но до этого момента старайтесь слушать только здравый смысл, который если говорит что здесь и сейчас будет удобно написать три аргумента, то значит нужно писать три аргумента. Не выворачивайте себя наизнанку если так велит какой-то человек написавший книгу. Он сорок лет учился и говорит о том что в самом начале вынесло бы мозг и ему так, будто бы это понятно всем. Но это вполне нормально и простительно.

И лично я советую посмотреть в сторону классов, они намного полезнее чем о них рассказывают те, кто пишет на `react` и на `frp` забывая что они насквозь пронизаны классами.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за разрвёрнутый ответ! Цель скрыть данные от пользователей я не преследовал, так как JavaScript-код по своей природе открытый и там нельзя хранить никаких важных данных. Целью и является, как Вы сказали, защита глобального пространства от засорения.

Answer (score -1):

Конечно же да - стоит избегать, разделите функции на несколько групп, самые простые, выполняющие элементарные вещи отдельно от более нагруженных и так до самых сложных или используйте классы, принцип тот же.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните на чем основано ваше утверждение

Comment: Да, поясните, пожалуйста. Вообще-то я делаю так, как Вы говорите. Какие-то совсем уж общие функции типа получения времени в желаемом формате выношу в отдельный файл. В том примере, что я привёл, у нас есть основная функция `initHeader()` и несколько вспомогательных простых функций, но они имеют отношение только к шапке. Мы сейчас обсуждаем, что делать именно с этими функциями - объявить их внутри основной, или же вне её. Во втором случае придётся передавать аргументы, а также каждый раз заново проводить ресурсозатратную процедуру захвата DOM-элементов внутри функций.

Comment: @Gurebu Bokofu - если эти функции не нужны больше нигде, то - выносить их за пределы не обязательно. Хорошая практика - не выносить лишних переменных и функций в глобальную область видимости, а еще советую прочитать про: `замыкание, функции изнутри`

Comment: @And, Не знаю, хотели ли Вы сказать, что приведённый мной подход правильный, но всё, что Вы сказали, лежит в основе данного метода.

Comment: @Gurebu Bokofu, сначала прочитайте свой вопрос, а после прочитайте мой коммент и я вас уверяю - вопросы отпадут сами по себе. ;)