# Как и когда лучше инициализировать переменные и классы в JavaScript, если их много?

Tags: javascript

Распространённая практика в современности - сжатие всех JS-файлов в один и подключение их в `<head>`. Работая с такой структурой, в какой момент и как следует инициализировать переменные и классы, чтобы расход памяти был оптимальный?

Поясню проблематику вопроса.

Мы, конечно, можем в `onload` проинициализировать все переменные, с которыми будем работать, но на конкретной странице сайта/приложения нам все переменные и не нужны: зачем инициализировать переменные, связанные с формой отправки, если мы на главной странице? А если это DOM-объекты, то мы их и не сможем проинициализировать, находясь на странице, где их нет (eсли мы, конечно, целиком не генерируем HTML на JS). Получается, что такой вариант не подходит.

В вопросе [JavaScript: стоит ли избегать стиля написания кода “функция в функции”?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617508/javascript-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment855073_617508) я предложил такую структуру кода, которая позволяет инициализировать переменные только тогда, когда они нужны. В момент написания текущего вопроса, ответов типа *"да, такой подход применять, потому что <обоснование>"* или *"нет, такого подхода следует избегать, потому что <обоснование>"* не было, но сам я без особых проблем применял данных подход, пока не начал работать с ES2015-классами.

Эти классы не могут быть использованы до объявления. Так как сначала писать классы внутри функции (чтобы проинициализировать их только тогда, когда они нужны), а потом внутри этой же функции писать вспомогательные - весьма скверный тон, встал вопрос: как следует инициализировать эти классы по необходимости?

Comment: 1 - Скрипты в `header` нынче уже моветон. 2 - Почитайте про модульный js

Comment: @ThisMan, откуда дровишки про моветон?

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD
Если серьёзно, полагаю он имеет ввиду, что надёжней запускать скрипты из конца документа, чтобы имеющуюся разметку уже обработал браузер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы смешиваете разные вещи: инициализацию и определение зависимостей.

Определение зависимостей - это те самые классы и функции, которым нужны другие классы и функции. Если все сделано правильно - то нет никакой причины избегать создания классов и функций сразу же. На это все, на самом деле, нужно совсем немного времени.

Инициализация же (связь с элементами DOM, настройка обработчиков событий, старт фоновых скриптов) должна делаться по требованию.

---

Конкретные советы. Для управления зависимостями воспользуйтесь модулями. Существуют такие библиотеки, как requirejs, systemjs. Существует такие инструменты как browserify и webpack.

Все они позволяют склеивать разные файлы в один так, чтобы они исполнялись не сразу, а по требованию.

Пример связи двух модулей. Формат AMD (Asynchronous Module Definition, асинхронное определение модуля):

```
//a.js
define(function () {
  return {
    foo: function () {
      console.log("Hello, world!");
    }
  }
});

//b.js
define(['a'], function (a) {
  return {
    bar: function () {
      a.foo();
    }
  }
});
```

Формат CommonJS (в браузере напрямую работать не будет - но инструменты для склейки модулей умеют такой формат обрабатывать):

```
//a.js
exports.foo = function () {
  console.log("Hello, world!");
}

//b.js
var a = require("a");
exports.bar = function () {
  a.foo();
}
```

Формат ES6, тоже не для браузера:

```
//a.js
export function foo() {
  console.log("Hello, world!");
}

//b.js
import foo from 'a';
export function bar() {
  foo();
}
```

---

По инициализации.

В библиотечных модулях - просто не трогайте DOM пока вас не попросят. Страница должна как-то указать какой файл нужно подключить и какую функцию вызвать. В простейшем случае - можно добавить на страницу второй тэг script, где инлайн-скриптом будет сделан вызов нужной функции. Или же можно воспользоваться атрибутами для указания этих данных (кстати, полное отсутствие инлайн-скриптов позволит запретить их через CSP, что повысит устойчивость ко взломам).

Любое обращение к DOM должно происходить не ранее чем при вызове функции или в конструкторе класса (исключение - чтение атрибутов, указывающих какой модуль грузить для инициализации). Причем очень желательно, чтобы элементы DOM были там не захардкожены - а выбирались на основе переданных параметров.

Если кусок разметки нужен модулю для своих нужд (например, это шаблон) - его лучше вынести в отдельный файл и грузить как модуль. browserify и webpack так умеют:

```
var template = require("./template.html"); // содержимое файла будет, скорее всего, "подклеено" в общий бандл в виде строкового литерала.
```

---

Ну и обязательно посмотрите на широко используемые фреймворки. Если не в плане использования - то хотя бы как там сделано. У того же Angular (не путать с AngilarJs) есть рекомендуемый набор инструментов для разработки и сборки. В принципе, никто вам не мешает поставить Angular по инструкции с их сайта, потом удалить его обратно - а инструментами пользоваться :)

Comment: https://github.com/vikingmute/webpack-basic-starter

Comment: @11111000000 сам по себе webpack автору вопроса не поможет. Ему нужны идеи по организации кода. Вот и я привел в качестве примера фреймворк, где организация кода довольно продумана. Если у вас есть другие идеи - пишите комментарии, свой ответ или дополняйте мой. А неконструктивную критику уберите.

Comment: свой ответ у меня уже есть, комментарий считаю конструктивным

Comment: Рекомендуете изучать инструменты Жужл. Изучать документацию - другое дело, однако в первую очередь - паттерны, во-вторую - конкретные реализации. Т.е. часть ответа про Ангуляр нельзя назвать конструктивной, разумеется, за исключением совета удалить его обратно.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за развёрнутый ответ!